# PHP Mailing Code Not Working

Tags: php, forms, contacts, mailer

This is my current code. Why is it not working? It sends mail, but in the `$message` section it doesn't pull from `$name`, `$phone`, or `$email`. Also, on the email itself, the `$from` doesn't work. The only thing that works correctly is `$to` and `$subject`.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "emailgoeshere@example.com";
$from = $_POST['email']; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $name . " " . $phone . " has the email:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['email'];

$headers = "From: <".$from. ">" ;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "We have Recieved your Enquiry, We will get back to you soon. We Appreciate Your Patient Thank You.";
}
?>


<div class="right-wrapper">
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <p class="contact-form-info">Leave your contact info below, and we'll contact you shortly:</p>
                    <form action="https://www.forevrmarketing.com/webdesigndemo/eddy1155/functions/send-mail.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name" name="name" id="name">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email" class="email" id="email">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="phone" class="phone" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="15">
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

                    <div class="loader" disabled><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    <p class="form-details form-era">Call us at <strong style="font-weight: 600">+65 9691 1155</strong> Or <br><span class="wts"><img src="img/icon.png" alt="WhatsApp Icon"></span> <strong style="font-weight: 600">Whatsapp</strong> us</p>
                    <p class="reponse"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your email and phone fields don't have a `name=` attribute, but two `class`es. Closing `</form>` is missing

Comment: Ty debigging the HTML form, the mail invocation from PHP and your MTA serperately. Don't publish details of a public site you are working on unles you have a specific reason to do so. Go read up in Email header injection and have a look at FAQ - https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Two fields in your form are missing `name` attributes and thus cannot be referenced as `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['phone']`.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email" class="email" id="email">
<input type="number" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="phone" class="phone" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="15">
```

should be

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="email" id="email">
<input type="number" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone" class="phone" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="15">
```

This should solve `$from`, `$phone` and `$email` being empty.

Also, in your `$message` line you could replace `$_POST['email']` with `$email`.

Finally, add a closing `</form>` to your code.

Comment: @Logan Glad it works. If this helped you solve your problem you are welcome to accept this as an answer so others know this question/problem has been resolved. Thx